# Return in lisp error

Tags: common-lisp

So i have this line of code as part of a function and it recieves the "no" as an argument.

```
(cond ( (avaliar-no (no-tabuleiro no)) (return no)))
```

The problem is when i do the `(return no)` i get this error :

```
Unknown block NIL in form
#S(COMPILER::MULTIPLE-TRANSFORMS-RECORD :FORMS (#
#) :ORIGINAL-PATH 3946)
```

Anyone know what this might be ?

Heres the whole function (its not finished yet)

```
(defun minimax (no estado)

(let ( (sucessores nil) (v nil))
  ;se o no for solucao entao retornamos esse nó e guardamos o seu custo na lista
  (cond ( (avaliar-no (no-tabuleiro no)) (return no)) ;falta fazer o (setf *valoresF* valorDoNo)
  ;se nao for solucao entao expandimo o nó
  (t(setf sucessores (no-sucessores no estado))))
  ;se o estado for min entao metemos o V a +oo e corremos o algoritmo para toda a lista de sucessores
  ;(cond ( (and(>= (length sucessores)1)(equal estado 'min)) (setf v 9999) 
          (loop (minimax (first sucessores) 'max) (setf sucessores (rest sucessores)) (setf v (min v *valoresF*)))))
```

Comment: Post the whole function please. Most probably you want `(return-from <function-name> no)` instead of `(return no)`.

Comment: As I said... try `(return-from minimax no)`.

Comment: thanks ! it worked fine !

Answer (score 6):

`RETURN` needs to return from *something*. This *something* would be a *block* named `NIL`. Thus it is just a shorter version of `(return-from nil ...`).

A named function creates a *block*, but not of name `NIL`. The name of the *block* is the name of the function. Thus you have to call `(return-from function-name ...)`.